# Replacing all occurrences of non-printable character in a file using its ascii value

Tags: file, unix, replace, character, non-printing-characters

I have a file `myFile.xml`which 
I want to run the `xmllint`command on for proper formatting.

It contains the ASCII character 26 (substitute char) because of which `xmllint` command is failing with parser error.

How can I replace all occurrences of this character with blank in this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked:

```
tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < file-with-binary-chars > clean-file
```

referred from here:

[ascii-control-characters](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix)

Comment: You should probably add to your answer that this command not only substitutes ASCII character 26 (decimal), but also every character not in the set `'\11\12\15\40-\176'` (octal).

Comment: Actually it _doesn't_ remove character 26, as this would be `\32` in octal notation.  But the road is clear.

Comment: @Alfe It does. The `-c` is for complement and `-d` is for delete. And of course, there's no such thing as a `26` character, just the ASCII value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `bash`, how about this:

```
sed $'s/\x1a//g' < FILENAME | xmllint
```

This uses the special `bash` notation `$'...'` which tells the `bash` to evaluate backslash sequences like the `\x1a` properly.